# Need help on MVVM. Closing one window and opening second window C#

Tags: c#, viewmodel

I want to close one window by close button click then open another window or child window. What am I doing wrong.

ViewModel:

```
private ICommand _closeCommand;
public ICommand CloseCommand
{
    get { return _closeCommand ?? (_closeCommand = new CommandHandler(() => MyClose(), _canExecute)); }
}

public void MyClose()
{
    SecondWindow window = new SecondWindow() { DataContext = new SecondWindowViewModel() };
    window.Show();
    App.Current.MainWindow.Close();
    App.Current.MainWindow = window;
}
```

Xmal:

```
<Button Command ="{Binding CloseCommand}" 
 CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Name="Close" Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="535,379,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
```

Comment: Well, you have to tell us what is happening, right?  Are you getting an error or something expected is not happening?

Comment: window.show() is not working. This is the error I am getting for window.Show(). 'SecondWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Show' and no extension method 'Show' accepting a first argument of type 'SecondWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)                                                                                          For App.Current.MainWindow = window;  
Cannot implicitly convert type 'SampleApplication.View.SecondWindow' to 'System.Windows.Window'

Comment: Well, show us SecondWindow class, as it appears you're not deriving from Window.

Answer (score 0):

Based the comment conversation we had, this is the error you're getting:

> 'SecondWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Show' and no
>   extension method 'Show' accepting a first argument of type
>   'SecondWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Which tells me that your problem is that you're not deriving from a Window class or any other class which contains the Show() method.  This speculation is further reinforced by the fact that you're getting the following error when you're trying to assign your SecondWindow class to the Mainwindow:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'SampleApplication.View.SecondWindow'
>   to 'System.Windows.Window'

Comment: I am Kinda new to MVVM. How do I derive window class.
public class ViewModelBase : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged

but it is not helping me out. Is there any way I can send you my sample application to you and you can take a look. Please help.

Comment: @MisuZAMAN Deriving from another class has nothing to do with MVVM.  You need to learn the basics of C#.  Post your relevant code in your original question.